# Equivalence of IF and WHERE

Tags: if-statement, fortran, where-clause, conditional-statements

We all know that the `DO` loop is more powerful than the `FORALL` statement in Fortran. That is, you can always substitute a `FORALL` by a `DO`, but not vice versa.

What about the `WHERE` statement and block?

Can I always substitute the `IF` by a `WHERE`? Is it always possible to code the conditionals and bifurcations with a `WHERE`, thus avoiding the `IF`?

Comment: The original intent of FORALL was to allow the masked array assignments to be done in parallel - it came from a variant called High Performance Fortran and was adopted into Fortran 95. Unfortunately, the semantics of FORALL were not conducive to parallelization, so Fortran 2008 added DO CONCURRENT which is not only more familiar-looking to Fortran programmers but also has better semantics for parallelization.  You may want to look at MERGE, which can, with some clever masks, be quite powerful.

Comment: Going on what @SteveLionel said, note that `MERGE` *can* be used inside the `WHERE` block while an `IF` statement *cannot*.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `FORALL` is purely an assignment statement or block, while `DO` is a more general flow-control construct.

Answer (score 10):

`WHERE` statements are reserved for arrays assignments and nothing else, e.g.:

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(100,100) :: a, b
... define a ...
WHERE(a < 0)
   b = 1
ELSEWHERE
   b = 0
ENDWHERE
```

If you tried adding in something, say a `WRITE` statement, inside the `WHERE` block, you would see something like the following compiling error (compiler dependent):

```
Error: Unexpected WRITE statement in WHERE block at (1)
```

---

**EDIT**

Note that nested `WHERE` blocks are legal:

```
WHERE(a < 0)
   WHERE( ABS(a) > 2)
      b = 2
   ELSEWHERE
      b = 1
   ENDWHERE
ELSEWHERE
   b = 0
ENDWHERE
```

Comment: OK, so the answer to the question above is a simple "NO".

Comment: Correct, it is a simple no answer. A simple 10 line piece of code also could have told you the same answer, rather than asking us :/